# What is the most speed efficient primality test available

Tags: prime-numbers, primality-test

I am trying to find out if a number is prime on a computer but I am only try a very few and far apart numbers so don't want to use a sieve. I am quite good at maths but am only doing my GCSEs so can you please explain the answers clearly. I am looking for the most time efficient primality test algorithm as my numbers quickly get to sizes like 2^2^20 which needs a very efficient primality test. I am really looking for a polynomial time algorithm.

Comment: If your number has no special form and is that large, you will have to be content with a probabilistic test. Miller-Rabin is probably the best approach.

Comment: See [Primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test).

Comment: In the case, you want to find a new record for the largest Mersenne-prime, use the Lucas-Lehmer-Test,

Comment: Isn't $2^{2^{20}} \approx 6 \times 10^{315652}$ a bit large? The estimated number of atoms in the universe is $10^{80}$ according to WA.

Comment: @mvw What does the number of atoms in the universe have to do with anything? It's still nowhere near the largest known primes, so it's demonstrably possible, at least in some cases, to decide.

Comment: @mvw To test $100$-digit-numbers for primality is abolutely routine today, but $2^{2^{20}}$ actually is big, but not a real challenge. Nevertheless, the test will take some time ...

Comment: It is a bound on the states the algorithm can use on a physical machine.

Comment: @mvw But we do not need $10^{100}$ steps to decide whether a $100$-digit is prime.

Comment: @Peter Sure, but it means you can not test for arbitrary large numbers. You have to concentrate on special ones, like the Mersenne primes.

Comment: Check out this : http://primes.utm.edu/ to see how large the largest known prime is.

Comment: @Peter There should be unknown primes below the largest known prime.

Comment: The test is for finding 2^2^x + 1 primes because they are constructible

Comment: These are Fermat numbers, and the smallest such number from which it is not known whether it is composite is $ \large {2^{2^{33}}+1}$ , which is huge indeed. $65537$ might be the largest such prime number, but noone yet knows.

Comment: @mvw Even general numbers with thousands of digits were proven prime with the elliptic-curve-primility-proving method. And if we only want to have a high probability, that the number is prime, Miller-Rabin is efficient enough, although it takes some time, $3\cdot 10^5$ digits is far from the limit of what can be done.

Comment: @13ros27 Pepin's test is efficient for your numbers, but you will need powerful hardware and much patience to decide whether $F_{33}$ is prime.

Comment: @mvw But you only need $2^{20}$ bits to accurately represent any number up to $2^{2^{20}}$. That's about a megabit. it's so small that I don't think you can find modern consumer storage media today where it _doesn't_ fit.

Comment: @Arthur I was aiming at the unspecified properties of the asked test.

Comment: @Peter Thank you for the interesting pointers.

Comment: The main purpose was as a learning experience rather than actually finding the next fermat number

Answer (score 3):

For numbers of ~315k digits, they either need to be of a special form (e.g. Proth, LLR, Mersenne, etc.) that allows a fast proof, or you will have to settle for a PRP test.  The record for general form proofs is about 35k digits, so 315k digits is far beyond today's practical limit.  ECPP is polynomial time in practice, and we don't know anything faster for general-form proofs.

Re PRP tests, your choices include Fermat, Euler (Jacobi), Euler (Plumb base 2), Miller-Rabin, BPSW, Frobenius and its variants, and more.  All polynomial in the size of the input.  Of course for speed you want some simple pre-tests such as trial division for small factors (perhaps implemented as a gcd with a large primorial, but it's the same thing), but after that you really need to run one of the tests.

Also critical at this size is the implementation.  In a test I did a few years ago with a 140k digit PRP, PFGW's Fermat test took under 6 minutes, GMP took 30 minutes, and Pari/GP took 63 minutes.  PFGW uses gwnum which is highly optimized for this operation on large numbers, while the GMP library is massively more portable, much easier to use in implementations, and is faster for smaller inputs (under ~2000 digits).  Using something other than these is probably going to be really, really slow.

The good news (maybe) is that it took only 6 minutes to run a Fermat test on a single 140k number.  315k digits should be reasonably practical.  You could also run a few numbers in parallel if desired.  Once you find something that passes, at this size it's very likely to be prime, and running a more stringent test like BPSW for more certainty should finish under a day.

Realistically at this size, just use [PFGW](https://sourceforge.net/projects/openpfgw/files/).  Once you found a candidate, you can try more bases or apply more stringent tests using various other tools.  If you have a range you're looking in, you want to use a sieve of some sort to efficiently remove small divisors.